# I cannot get Mono for Android activity preference to work

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin.android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

In my mono for android app I want to save a user setting for an activity into the activities preference. I do this whenever the user changes this value:

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = GetPreferences(FileCreationMode.Append);
        ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
        editor.PutInt(NO_PIXELS_PER_HOUR_KEY, m_noPixelsPerHour);
        editor.Commit();
```

where NO_PIXELS_PER_HOUR_KEY  is:

```
private const string NO_PIXELS_PER_HOUR_KEY = "PIXELS_PER_HOUR";
```

This value should then be loaded again in the actvity's OnCreate method:

```
ISharedPreferences preferences = GetPreferences(FileCreationMode.Append); 
int tempNoPixelsPerHour = preferences.GetInt(NO_PIXELS_PER_HOUR_KEY, -1);
        if (tempNoPixelsPerHour == -1)
            m_noPixelsPerHour = (int)(m_deviceHeight * 0.25);
        else
            m_noPixelsPerHour = tempNoPixelsPerHour;
```

The problem is that the value does not seem to be persisting! Whenever I go out of the activity and back into it the default value of -1 is returned. I don't know whether it is not saving properly or not loading properly. Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks,
Dave

Comment: what is ISharedPreferences? put breakpoints and see what value you're persisting.

Comment: ISharedPreferences is the object returned by Android for managing the activity's / apps preferences. On one occasion I persisted 241 but it still returned -1.

Comment: Your code look fine, try [this](https://github.com/gshackles/Sample-Projects/blob/master/MonoDroid/MonoDroidSamples/MonoDroidSamples/DemoActivities/Preferences/PreferencesActivity.cs) working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know about mono for android but in android we call getsharedpreferences() in java. Here you're calling only the preferences which can be any preference but the settings preference. You can try something like getdefaultsharedpreference or something like that.

EDIT : I'm not sure but you can try this..

```
ISharedPreferences _preferences = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(your_context)
```

Comment: Thanks Parvaz. It works when I access the ISharedPreferences object as  you describe:    `ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);`